# How to redirect from one blade view to another blade view, and pass dynamically generated variable to it?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6, laravel-route

In my view , let's call it View-A, I get an input from user in a prompt and assign it to a variable, and then I need to load in browser another view, say View B, while passing it that variable.

Say, in my `viewA.blade.php`, I have taken user's input and assigned it to variable `usersInput`. Now I need to send it to view B, whose route in web.php is defined at `Route::get('editRecord', 'MyController@displayEditRecordView')->name('editRecordFormView');`.

Question is how do I load route(`editRecordFormView`) in browser and pass `usersInput` variable to it, from javascript written in my blade view?

---

@Tushar **In  in my ViewA.blade.php:**

```
$.ajax({
    url: url_editRecordView.url,
    data: {
        usersInput: dataToSend.usersInput,
    },
    method: "get",
    cache: false,
    success: function (dataReturned, stringStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log("dataReturned from mYController.displayEditRecordFormView:-");
        console.log(dataReturned);//check
        console.log("Type of dataReturned:-" + typeof dataReturned); //SAME DATA COMES BACK, AS THE DATA I SENT
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, stringStatus, stringExceptionThrown) {
        alert("Error! status: " + stringStatus + " ExceptionThrown: " + stringExceptionThrown);//check
    }
});
```

**In my MyController:**

```
public function displayEditRecordFormView (Request $request) {
    error_log("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");//check
    error_log("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");//check
    $title= $request->input('usersInput');
    error_log("In displayEditRecordFormView: title: ".$title);//check
    $allPaintingsArray = $this->getAllPaintingsArraySanitized();
    $data = [
        "allPaintingsArray"=>$allPaintingsArray ,
        "title"=>$title
    ];

    return view("paintings.editRecordForm")->with("allGoodData", $data);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of AJAX call why don't use something like this:

```
var url = "/editRecord?usersInput=dataToSend.usersInput;
window.location.href = url;
```

catch variable In controller:

```
$title= request()->filled('usersInput');// or find a way according to Laravel version
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of AJAX. Just set an event handler for when the user gives an input, and send a request containing the user input to a method in your View-A controller via AJAX and from there you can redirect to View-B along with the value that you got from the request.

**EDITED**

Instead of using *view() method* try using **redirect() method** like this:

```
return redirect()->route('editRecordFormView', ['input' => 'userInput']);
```

To know more about redirects please refer to [this](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/redirects#redirecting-named-routes)

Comment: Hey I am trying exactly that. But "from there you can redirect to View-B along with the value that you got from the request." never happens. It never redirects. Just the AJAX response comes back with the same data which i sent in the request. Redirect never happens.

Comment: I have edited my answer, please check if it makes things work ?! :)

Comment: `net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` and the controller method is being called a ton of times.

Comment: I think there is some sort of confusion. You are sending the input to the same method and then redirecting to it. Instead try to create an intermediate method just to get the input and then redirect to the displayEditRecordFormView method in your controller via **action() method** and from there return view as you were doing earlier.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217502/discussion-between-tushar-and-nxa).